# How to pass UTC time into react input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to provide the ability to edit a date in react. The date from the backend in is UTC formatted. It would be nice as well to have the ability to convert the input back into UTC from the input. Is there a quick way to do this without parsing UTC?

I tried using a standard date input and it does not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.